# typeof isn't working as expected with ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to create simple form validation with AJAX and PHP but the usage of `typeof` is not working as expected.

It works well unless I'm getting an empty response which means all fields have passed the validation.

In that case, nothing happens and the last input remains with its error classes and Cart `div` is not changing to the Success `div` as intended upon a successful request.

A typical response in JSON:

```
{
  last_name: "The Last name is required", 
  email: "The Email is required", 
  city: "The City is required", 
  np_branch: "The Np branch is required"
}
```

Obviously, if one of the values passed the PHP validation its not added to the array. Please note that the error values might change for each key depending on the error thus checking for the error message is not an option.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType:"json",
  data: {
    last_name: l_name.val(),
    email: email.val(),
    city: city.val(),
    np_branch: np_branch.val()
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // If all fields passed validation we hide the Cart div and show the Success div
    if (typeof(data['last_name']) == "undefined" && typeof(data['email']) == "undefined" && typeof(data['city']) == "undefined" && typeof(data['np_branch']) == "undefined") {
      $('.cart').css({ "display":"none" });
      $('.success').css({ "display":"block" });
    }
    // Checking whether the response contains a last_name error
    if (typeof(data['last_name']) != "undefined" && data['last_name'] !== null) {
      l_name.addClass("error");
      $('#l_name-err').css({ "display":"block" });
    } else if (l_name.hasClass('error')) {
      l_name.removeClass("error");
      $('#l_name-err').css({ "display":"none" });
    }
    // Checking whether the response contains a email error
    if (typeof(data['email']) != "undefined" && data['email'] !== null) {
      email.addClass("error");
      $('#email-err').css({ "display":"block" });
    } else if (email.hasClass('error')) {
      email.removeClass("error");
      $('#email-err').css({ "display":"none" });
    }
    // Checking whether the response contains a city error
    if (typeof(data['city']) != "undefined" && data['city'] !== null) {
      city.addClass("error");
      $('#city-err').css({ "display":"block" });
    } else if (city.hasClass('error')) {
      city.removeClass("error");
      $('#city-err').css({ "display":"none" });
    }
    // Checking whether the response contains a np_branch error
    if (typeof(data['np_branch']) != "undefined" && data['np_branch'] !== null) {
      np_branch.addClass("error");
      $('#branch-err').css({ "display":"block" });
    } else if (np_branch.hasClass('error')) {
      np_branch.removeClass("error");
      $('#branch-err').css({ "display":"none" });
    }
  }
});
```

Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to understand - when does `typeof` not work, exactly?

Comment: If `data` is not set. As soon as all values pass the validation, PHP doesn't return anything thus `data` is not set - in this case `typeof` doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, then. Well, if that's the case, you can check if you have `data` first. Not sure what you want to do for it but a simple `if (!data) data = {}` at the start might be all you need.

Comment: Nothing seemed to work although your suggestion was useful. I just solved it by changing the PHP side of things, now instead of giving no `data` it gives a `{success:1}` JSON response. So instead of checking whether `data` is empty, I check if `data.success` equals `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just check (unless I misunderstood the logic):

```
// If data.last_name is defined and has some value show error message, else remove it
if(data['last_name']) {
 l_name.addClass("error");
 $('#l_name-err').show();
} else {
  l_name.removeClass("error");
  $('#l_name-err').hide();
}
```

Also, typeof should not be written the way you have it remove the "()". It should be:
`typeof data['np_branch'] !== "undefined"` instead of `typeof(data['np_branch']) != "undefined"`

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed it by changing the PHP output upon successful validation. It seems like checking if `data` is not set is not the best way to do that. Also, I'm now using a similar format to what you suggested, just without the brackets `data.last_name`